# Align button to the center

Tags: magento-1.7, template, css, magento-community, styles

I need to **center-align a button in a login form** and I can't manage to do it. The reason for that is that there is a css property inherited from `div .page` (`text-align: left`). I tried to assign the property text-align:center to the element itsef, but there is no effect, and the .page property seems to prevail over it.
I saw that the `< div class="page"` comes from `1column.phtml`, so it affects all my page.

Anyone knows how could I center-align the button?

Comment: Try To This Link It May Be Help You... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595315/center-a-form-that-contains-a-button-in-a-div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/7Laf8/

Basically, place your button into a div with centred text:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

With the following styles:

```
.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

.button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```